# Incorrect Request.Browser.MinorVersion for Safari 5.1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari

ASP.NET web application, OS: Windows 7, Browser: Safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7)

In server-side code **Request.Browser.MinorVersion** gives me the value of **1.0**

Can anybody please tell me the reason, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version is in the fallowing format major.minor.revision.build. According to this the major is 5 and the minor is 1.
You can also see here that the latest version of safari for windows is 5.1:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history

Comment: The scheme is actually: major.minor[.build[.revision]], but thanks, now I understand why MinorVersion gives me 1.0.

Comment: Still, how could I get the build number without parsing the Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]?